# Saving a exact response in file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to save exact response from Jmeter in a file?

e.g. -  I have a response as email only so I want to save this email address only in a file with a success and failure but If I am saving a file as xml its giving a whole bunch of code otherwise if I save it as a csv file it's giving all sort of infomation other than a email address. Pls help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to save the whole response - [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener is what you're looking for.
2. If you need to store a part of the response - first of all get the necessary part with i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor). Once you have JMeter Variable holding required value i.e. `email` you can add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   sample_variables=email

   and `${email}` variable value will be stored along with other results.

   NB

   - you need to restart JMeter to pick the property up
   - you can also pass it via -J command line argument like:

     ```
     jmeter -Jsample_variables=email -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
     ```

References:

- [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)